# How to deactivate my previous version retained .apk in Play Store

Tags: google-play, release-management, google-play-console

I have checked Google Documentation and other answers also - 
It tells you how to Deactivate your previous release version at the time of publishing new release version, **but it doesn't tell you how to deactivate your previous release version if you have already retained it.**

[image: Google Documentation]

I want to deactivate my 3rd release version but their isn't any option mentioned... 
Since, **I need Single-APK release, not Multi-APK-release.**

[image: Play store Version Deactivation]

Do I have to unpublish & re-publish my app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Retained APKs can only be deactivated, if you have newer update for roll-out to your previous release.

Go to your App releases tab under Release Management (Google Play Console) and scroll down you will find `APKs to retain` and you can deactivate the previous outdated releases.

[image: Deactivating previously Retained APK releases]

----- Update to my Answer, as of Oct 2020 -----

Simple answer for this is **"Now you can't"**. With App Bundles it deactivates your previous release versions at the time of new version release.

**Just for Demo Purpose (Step by Step)**
Tried it with *Internal Test Track* holds same for *Production Track* as well.

**Step 1.** Go to Create Release for creating a new update release. Since, I already have uploaded the App Bundle, will go to Edit Release.

[image: Internal Test Track - Step 1]

**Step 2.** You will see earlier version of your app. Click on the Retain button. **By default, you don't need to take any action, since *Google Play* takes care of it, by deactivating it by default.**

[image: Internal Test Track - Step 2]

**Step 3.** Once you click Retain, you will see the button changes to Deactivate.

[image: Internal Test Track - Step 3]

**Step 4.** But you will see an Error while trying to Review.

[image: Internal Test Track - Step 4]

**Step 5.** Once you click on *View Error Messages*, you will see something like this.

[image: Internal Test Track - Step 5]

**Step 6.** And if you scroll down, you will also notice a Red Icon Error, which means you can't surpass this error until and unless you Deactivate the earlier version, which you have Retained.

[image: Internal Test Track - Step 6]

**Step 7.** Go Back and then Edit your Release Version.

[image: Internal Test Track - Step 7]

**Step 8.** Click on Deactivate.

[image: Internal Test Track - Step 8]

**Step 9.** After Deactivating you will notice that the Error is gone and also the Red Icon error is gone. Now you can review and publish your release version.

[image: Internal Test Track - Step 9]

This has become invalid now after so many updates to Google Play.

Comment: there is no "APKs to retain" option now, what is alternative?

Comment: Yes. Now you can't. With `App Bundles` it deactivates your previous release versions at the time of new version release.

Comment: What if we want to stop test channel and ignore the existing build? for example we already push build to production, and open test will not be used , we can pause the track, but the old bundle in the track still active

Answer (score 4):

Since the Play Console changes so much, here's the solution to deactivate retained APKs at the time of this post:

1. Goto "Release Management" for your app.
2. Next, you want to create a new production release. There are a few way to get to that screen, one way is to go to "App Releases", select "Manage" under the production section, and then click the "Create Release" button.
3. You do **NOT** need to upload a new APK. Instead, if you scroll down you will see a list of current production APKs that you are currently retaining. Next to each one should be a "Deactivate" button. Click to deactivate one or more retained APKs. Be careful you retain your current APK release (unless you don't want to).
4. Give your release a name, something like "0" will work.
5. Finally, click "Save", then "Review". You may get some warnings informing you about the APKs you are deactivating as well as the potential loss of device support you may be causing. You can acknowledge those and continue to submit the release.

That should be it! The deactivated APKs should no longer appear in the list of retained production APKs for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and I removed the previously created app and then recreated the app with all details and then my app was published.
This normally happens when there is already an app available with other signature and with same version number.

Steps:

1. Remove the previously created draft
2. Create new app
3. Publish the bundle app

Answer (score -1):

Here's the Google Support's official suggestions about how to deactivate old app bundles or APK.

> Please follow the given steps to deactivate non-compliant app bundles
> or APK
>
> 1. Go to your Play Console.
> 2. Select the app.
> 3. Go to the track where the non-compliant APK or app bundle is.
> 4. Near the top right of the page, click Create new release. (You may need to click Manage track first)
>
> -If the release with the violating APK is in a draft state, discard the release.
>
> 5. Under the new release page, you can choose to:
>
> -Upload a new, compliant APK/app bundle and make sure the new release is rolled out 100% to completely deactivate the non-compliant APK:
> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149
>
> -Not upload any new APK/app bundle (publish an empty release to just deactivate the non-compliant old version).
>
> 6. Regardless of what you choose in step 5, please make sure that the non-compliant version of APK/app bundle is under the Not included
>    section of this new release. For further guidance, please see the "Not
>    included (app bundles and APKs)" section in this Play Console Help
>    article:
>    https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859348#zippy=%2Cnot-included-app-bundles-and-apks
> 7. To save any changes you make to your release, select Save.
> 8. When you've finished preparing your release, select Review release. If the non-compliant APK is released to multiple tracks, repeat steps
>    3-8 in each track