# How to remove Old APK from from Play Store Console

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I am at lost on how to remove an old APK uploaded to the Play Store in 2020. We have a warning on the Play Store console that our app contains non complaint SDK as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Non Complaint SDK Warning]

Notice how that warning says it was build version code 150. The problem is that this build was uploaded on October of 2020 and this is November of 2022!

[image: Play Store App Explorer]

This version has ZERO releases and no install

[image: App bundle explorer]

I have replaced this build on the closed testing track where it was listed. I have also uploaded newer versions of the app to the open, closed, internal and production track.

There has been dozens of build released on top of that build. The newer builds does not have the flagged SDK versions. Yet each time I upload a new .aab build the Play Store validation flags it as in violation and referenced an old build.

I have opened three support ticket with no success. Anyone know how I can remove an old build that has no release, has been replaced, has no install, has no tester, never made it to production.

Comment: you cannot remove old apk from playstore

Comment: Whats the alternative? The Play Store validator keeps referencing this APK, when its not in use

Comment: Google just wants you to deactivate the problematic version. May be this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624580/how-to-deactivate-my-previous-version-retained-apk-in-play-store